# Ionic Framework: how to disable bounce effect in slider box?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on an app that has fullscreen slides, the thing is that I want to be able to stop the bounce effect whenever I'm either on the first slide or the last slide.

That is, if I'm on the start slide, disable the bouncing effect when dragging from the left. Likewise, if I'm on the last slide, disable the bouncing effect when dragging from the right. Is there a way to implement this?

(I know that Ionic has attribute name `hasBounce`, but that only works for the `ion-content` directive, and it only works for the top and the bottom)

Answer (score 5):

You could use `has-bouncing` on ion-content

```
<ion-content 
   has-bouncing="false"
   start-y="55"
   padding="true"
   has-tabs="true"
   has-header="true">
```

Comment: Wow searched for this thing just an hour after you replied to a 2-months question! It works and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

working in ionic 1.3.1 ;)

i searched in lib/ionic/jsionic.bundle.js

```
.directive('ionSlideBox', [
  '$animate',
  '$timeout',
  '$compile',
  '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate',
  '$ionicHistory',
  '$ionicScrollDelegate',
function($animate, $timeout, $compile, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicHistory, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      autoPlay: '=',
      doesContinue: '@',
      slideInterval: '@',
      showPager: '@',
      pagerClick: '&',
      disableScroll: '@',
      onSlideChanged: '&',
      activeSlide: '=?',
      bounce: '@'
    },
....
```

> ,
>             bounce: '@'

so bounce is working :)

```
<ion-slide-box bounce="false" ></ion-slide-box>
```